# Files in Python - reading in a file with lists

Tags: python, list, file-io

I have been given a file to read in with data such as:

```
[420, True, "Hello", 6.9]

[["How", "are", "you"], False, {"chicken":"nuggets"}, 666]
```

Each line in the .txt is enclosed in `[]`.

```
newfile = open('file.txt', 'r')
lines = newfile.readlines()
all = []
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip('\n')
    line = line[1:-1]
    line=line.split(', ')
    all += [line]
cleaning_up = [item for row in all for item in row]
```

This seems to work fine for any items in my list bar the `["How", "are", "you"]` as it gets split into

```
["How", 

"are", 

"you"]
```

when I print each item in the list containing all my data. Is there any way I could rectify this to keep the entire list as a single element as opposed to three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use eval to convert the strings to lists.

```
newfile = open('file.txt', 'r') 
lines = newfile.readlines()

all = []
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip('\n')
    line = eval(line)
    all.append(line)
cleaning_up = [item for row in all for item in row]
```

Comment: Thank you! That also saves me from having to check the type each piece of input is and sort through that. You saved me a headache!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) from the `ast` module to parse a string containing Python data structures.

E.g.

```py
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('[["How", "are", "you"], False, {"chicken":"nuggets"}, 666]')
[['How', 'are', 'you'], False, {'chicken': 'nuggets'}, 666]
```

So, in your loop you can do

```py
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip('\n')
        all.append(ast.literal_eval(line))
```